# VSCode Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal. Not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When I select a line of code in Python and press Shift + Enter the whole code gets replaced by a new line. I went to Keyboard Shortcuts and deleted most of the other Keybindings that used Shift + Enter but it is still occurring. I am working on a remote env through ssh maybe that's why? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running `Developer: Inspect Key Mappings` in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

Comment: @starball
Help: About

Version: 1.87.2 (Universal)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:21:31.043Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.1.0


Troubleshoot keybidings:
2024-03-25 12:53:14.063 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving shift+[Enter]
2024-03-25 12:53:14.063 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 7 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.

Inspect key mappings:
No shift+enter.

Comment: **into your question post**